# Dividing a table with its another column in Python/ R

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, multiple-columns

I have a table in a text file, which looks like this:

```
V4     V1  V2   V3   V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10  V11  V12  COMMON   SUBS
GENE1  1   37   40   .   -   7   9   1   15   14   8    567.4    145
GENE2  5   90   93   .   -   12  39  0   15   35   0    400.0    58.5
GENE3  6   278  281  .   +   22  0   12  10   30   18   100.344  0.009
GENE4  2   812  815  .   -   4   0   0   0    0    2    38.33    4.698
```

To generate this table in R :

```
 m <- data.frame("V4" = c("GENE1","GENE2","GENE3","GENE4"), "V1" = c(1,5,6,2), "V2" = c("37",90,278,812), "V3" = c(40,93,281,815), "V5"=c(".",".",".","."), "V6"=c("-","-","+","-"), "V7"=c(7,12,22,4), "V8"=c(9,39,0,0), "V9"=c(1,0,12,0), "V10" = c(15,15,10,0), "V11" = c(14,35,30,0), "V12"= c(8,0,18,2), "COMMON"=c(567.4,400,100.344,38.33), "SUBS"=c(145,58.5,0.009,4.698))
```

when I read it with R:

```
m = read.delim("RawNumbers.txt", header=F)
head(m)
      V4  V1   V2   V3 V5 V6  V7  V8  V9  V10  V11  V12   COMMON     SUBS
0  GENE1   1   37   40  .  -   7   9   1   15   14    8  567.400  145.000
1  GENE2   5   90   93  .  -  12  39   0   15   35    0  400.000   58.500
2  GENE3   6  278  281  .  +  22   0  12   10   30   18  100.344    0.009
3  GENE4   2  812  815  .  -   4   0   0    0    0    2   38.330    4.698
```

I need to divide each value in column `V7 to V9` with values in `COMMON` column, and from `V10 to V12` with values in `SUBS` column.
I am doing this division with `Python` with the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import codecs
doc = codecs.open('RawNumbers.txt')
df = pd.read_csv(doc, sep='\t')
col_division = [ 'V7',  'V8',  'V9']
df[col_division] = df[col_division] / df['COMMON']
col_division_two = [ 'V10',  'V11',  'V12']
df[col_division_two] = df[col_division_two] / df['SUBS']
```

However in this step, I receive an error of :

```
raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
```

How can I fix this error, or how can I do this division in R instead of Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in R, this should work:

```r
m[,c("V7","V8","V9")] <- m[,c("V7","V8","V9")] / m$COMMON
m[,c("V10","V11","V12")] <- m[,c("V10","V11","V12")] / m$SUBS
```

If you know the position of your columns in the dataframe, you can write:

```r
m[,7:9] <- m[,7:9] / m[,13]
m[,10:12] <- m[,10:12] / m[,14]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added the reproducible example in the question

Comment: Thanks, it works! Would it be a way that I would not need to write the name of the columns individually but give a range?

Comment: You're welcome ! I edited my answer to provide a way of doing the division without naming columns

Answer (score 3):

In R, using `dplyr` you could also use `mutate_at()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V7:V9), list(div = ~.x/COMMON)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V10:V12), list(div = ~.x/SUBS))
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "V4     V1  V2   V3   V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10  V11  V12  COMMON   SUBS
GENE1  1   37   40   .   -   7   9   1   15   14   8    567.4    145
GENE2  5   90   93   .   -   12  39  0   15   35   0    400.0    58.5
GENE3  6   278  281  .   +   22  0   12  10   30   18   100.344  0.009
GENE4  2   812  815  .   -   4   0   0   0    0    2    38.33    4.698")
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python, you could use `div`, and pass `axis='rows'`:

```
col_division = [ 'V7',  'V8',  'V9']
df[col_division] = df[col_division].div(df['COMMON'], axis='rows')
col_division_two = [ 'V10',  'V11',  'V12']
df[col_division_two] = df[col_division_two].div(df['SUBS'], axis='rows')
```

Comment: Thank you, this solutions works nicely! Would it be a way that I would not need to write the name of the columns individually but give a range?

Comment: `df.loc[:,'V7':'V9']`?

Answer (score 2):

With `base R`, you can use the following code to make it

```
m[c("V7","V8","V9","V10","V11","V12")] <- 
  m[c("V7","V8","V9","V10","V11","V12")]/data.frame(replicate(3,m$COMMON),replicate(3,m$SUBS))
```

such that

```
> m
     V4 V1  V2  V3 V5 V6         V7         V8          V9          V10          V11          V12  COMMON    SUBS
1 GENE1  1  37  40  .  - 0.01233698 0.01586183 0.001762425    0.1034483 9.655172e-02 5.517241e-02 567.400 145.000
2 GENE2  5  90  93  .  - 0.03000000 0.09750000 0.000000000    0.2564103 5.982906e-01 0.000000e+00 400.000  58.500
3 GENE3  6 278 281  .  + 0.21924579 0.00000000 0.119588615 1111.1111111 3.333333e+03 2.000000e+03 100.344   0.009
4 GENE4  2 812 815  .  - 0.10435690 0.00000000 0.000000000    0.0000000 0.000000e+00 4.257131e-01  38.330   4.698
```